# Calculate average within a specified range

Tags: r

I am using the 'diamonds' dataset from ggplot2 and am wanting to find the average of the 'carat' column. However, I want to find the average every 0.1:

**Between**

0.2 and 0.29

0.3 and 0.39

0.4 and 0.49

etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: I don't have any code, I know it's bad but I have no idea where to start beyond just the mean() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `aggregate` to `mean` by group which is calculated with `carat %/% 0.1`

```
library(ggplot2)
averageBy <- 0.1
aggregate(diamonds$carat, list(diamonds$carat %/% averageBy * averageBy), mean)
```

Which gives mean by `0.1`

> ```
>    Group.1         x
> 1      0.2 0.2830764
> 2      0.3 0.3355529
> 3      0.4 0.4181711
> 4      0.5 0.5341423
> 5      0.6 0.6821408
> 6      0.7 0.7327491
> ...
> ```

Comment: It works. Thank you, however I don't understand how the aggregate() function works, even after searching it up. Do you mind summarising it and why it does the job?

Comment: @Ghrafkly First argument is numeric values; second argument is vector of groups (how values in first argument should be grouped, check `diamonds$carat %/% averageBy`); third argument - what to do with grouped values.

Comment: Thanks mate. Pretty neat function